# Combining input XML to produce another XML output

Tags: xslt

Trying to build a POC that does the following:
Given a short input XML, take the values from it and insert them into a larger XML file of a known format.
So if this was my input XML:

```
<root>
 <transaction ID="TX123" source-system="xyz" timestamp="2015-10-15T14:20:35.954Z" dest-system="abc" status="success" applicationID="some_app" originator="MQ">
 </transaction>
</root>
```

And i'd have to take these values and insert them into this: [MQ FTE Transfer Log message format](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqfte/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wmqfte.doc%2Fsingle_message_format.htm)

I'd have to insert the values in the **transferSet** node (timestamp) and **metaDataSet**.
What would the XSLT have to look like in order to get this done?

Thanks a bunch in advance!
Slava.

Comment: Could you post your other input here, please (pick one of the three that your link points to...). Also include what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Your XLS should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>    

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <transaction>
        <!-- more elements... -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="transaction"/>
    </transaction>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="transaction">
    <transferSet>
        <xsl:attribute name="startTime"><xsl:value-of select="@timestamp" /></xsl:attribute>
        <metaDataSet>       
            <metaData key="com.ibm.wmqfte.SourceAgent"><xsl:value-of select="@source-system"/></metaData>
            <!-- more elements... -->
        </metaDataSet>
    </transferSet>
</xsl:template>
```

With your source input, it should generate an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transaction>
    <transferSet startTime="2015-10-15T14:20:35.954Z">
        <metaDataSet>
            <metaData key="com.ibm.wmqfte.SourceAgent">xyz</metaData>
        </metaDataSet>
    </transferSet>
</transaction>
```